# Show warning message with datepicker if within specified date

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, validation, datepicker

I'm trying to re-word this as I didn't really get many responses at all for something I think must be quite simple in logical terms.

I basically want an input field with a datepicker.

If the date selected falls within 21 days from todays date, I'd like a subtle message above or below.

What's the best way to do this, javascript, jquery or html5?

Answer (score 0):

$( "#delivery_date" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    onSelect : function(date, picker){
        var today = new Date().toISOString();
        var selectedDay = date.toISOString();
        if(today > selectedDay){
            $(elm).innerHTML = "selected date is less than today's date";
        }
    }
});

Comment: $( "#delivery_date" ).datepicker({ minDate: "+3W", maxDate: "", dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" onSelect : function(date, picker){ //just write your compare Logic and just show the error message if}});

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to compare dates and show the error... I'm asking for help on how to write it

Comment: Besides, wouldn't leaving the minDate value in there, still mean the selection would be restricted to after three weeks from today? I'd like to remove any selection restriction and just show a message if the date is within three weeks. Could you please show the full code example?

Comment: Okay thanks for that, but how would it work if the restricted period was three weeks or 21 days from today?

Comment: Sorry but the above doesn't work. No message is displayed, and it just appears to show the default datepicker allowing any selection.

Comment: Put simply, I want to use the minDate idea, but instead of disabling the dates within the period, I want them to be able to be selected, but for a message to be displayed. Surely that's simple to do?